# Error when saving in Textmate - No parent folder for “filename” when saving existing file in existing folder

Tags: textmate

I open a folder in Textmate, and select a file for editing. When I go to save the edited file, it indicates there is no parent folder, and asks if I want to create it. If I copy the edits, close without saving, re-open the file, paste the edits, and save, it saves correctly.

It seems like this is time dependent. The folder is on the local machine.

Comment: I've not seen this behavior. Are you able to reproduce on a clean install (https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Reverting-To-Defaults)? What about on other machines?

Comment: This worked, if you post it as a solution I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: This returned, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [Reverting to Defaults](http://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Reverting-To-Defaults).

Because link only answers are frowned upon, here's the contents of that document as though said by Yoda:

By reverting to default settings, many problems may be solved.

Remove these folders, after quitting TextMate, you must.

Lose customizations, you will.

> - ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate
> - ~/Library/Caches/com.macromates.TextMate/BundlesIndex.binary
> - ~/Library/Preferences/com.macromates.TextMate.plist
> - ~/.tm_properties

[image: a picture of yoda, this is]